# Apply sass variable to all elements of the parent

Tags: css, angular, sass

I have an Angular project with different components. I have a base `_colors.scss` that contains all of my color variables. These colors are broken up as "themes". However, the color variable does not take effect if the variable is called from within a child element.  Is there a way to make sure the variable is accessible to all of the nested classes within the parent theme class?

My `_colors.scss` file :

```
.brand-one { $color-primary: red }
.brand-two { $color-primary: blue }
.brand-three { $color-primary: green }
```

My Angular component's scss file:

```
@import '../assets/scss/colors';

.brand-one {
  .header{
    background: $color-primary;
  }
}
brand-two {
.header {
  background: $color-primary;
}

brand-three {
.header {
  background: $color-primary;
}
```

But this is is not working. Is there any special selector like the `~` I can use perhaps?

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you should declare variables inside a class?

colours.scss

```
$color-brand-one: red;
```

Component

```
@import '../assets/scss/colors';

.brand-one {
  .header{
    background: $color-brand-one;
  }
}
```